# Esapi not working in Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, esapi

I am using esapi 2.1.0 jar in our application for certain input validation.

It is working perfectly in development environment where we are using Apache Tomcat.

In SIT we have WebSphere 7 and jdk 1.6. Initially it was throwing an exception stating ESAPI.properties cannot be loaded, then I added it to the class path and now an error is being thrown:

```
Caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator(initialization failure)
```

The esapi 2.1.0 jar is available in classpath.

Comment: Try to change class load policy, parent last.

Comment: Hi Salih ...thanks for your comments ... My doubt is that is there any version comparability issue...bcoz its working perfectly in dev env

Comment: You need to provide full stack trace, as there should be some nested info why intialization is failing.

Comment: Hi Gas ... Thanks for your comments... Pls find the Stack trace :                                      Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :org.owasp.reference.DefaultValidator(initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.forName(Class.java:136)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.validator(ESAPI.java:191)

Comment: Where did you put that esapi jar?

Comment: In the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: List all the jars you have in WEB-INF/lib, try to edit your post if possible instead adding comments. What JDK did you use with Tomcat?

Comment: don't forget about validation.properties.